# Getting CSS grid areas to stack on mobile (single column layout)

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to get CSS Grid blocks to stack on top of each other when viewed on small screens. I know I can write media queries to change two columns to one. But I thought Grid could handle this without them?

I thought I could achieve this with auto-fit on columns. However, I think I may of misunderstood how this works?

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(400px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "leftCol rightTop" "leftCol rightBottom";
  height: 100vh;
}

.leftCol {
  grid-area: leftCol;
  background-color: pink;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100;
}

.rightBottom {
  grid-area: rightBottom;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100;
}

.rightTop {
  grid-area: rightTop;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="leftCol"></div>
  <div class="rightBottom"></div>
  <div class="rightTop"></div>
</div>
```

When the screen is below 400px, the right hand column just disappears. I was expecting them to stack on top of each other.

For example:

[image: Grid mock up]

[CodePen Example](https://codepen.io/grantsmith/pen/ZdZrqa?editors=1100)

Comment: Why would you not want the control that media queries will provide you with?

Comment: I would ask, why write them when they are not required? [Look Ma, No Media Queries!](https://css-tricks.com/look-ma-no-media-queries-responsive-layouts-using-css-grid/)

Comment: Also, maybe use flexbox instead of grid https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I have this working in Flexbox, but I trying to understand how to achieve this in CSS Grid

Comment: try looking at the grid behavior when you don't have `grid-template-areas` or any of the `grid-area` definitions - you'll see the grid items stacking as the window size reduces...

Answer (score 3):

> I am trying to get CSS Grid blocks to stack on top of each other when viewed on small screens. I know I can write media queries to change two columns to one. But I thought Grid could handle this without them? I thought I could achieve this with `auto-fit` on columns.

**You can.**

Here you go:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(400px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.leftCol     { background-color: pink; }
.rightBottom { background-color: yellow; }
.rightTop    { background-color: blue; }
body         { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="leftCol"></div>
  <div class="rightBottom"></div>
  <div class="rightTop"></div>
</div>
```

[revised codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gNyqRJ?editors=1100)

---

**Here's the problem with your original code:**

The `repeat()` function allows you to render a pattern of tracks in the grid container.

With `auto-fit` or `auto-fill`, the `repeat()` function will render as many tracks as possible without overflowing the container.

By itself, your code works as you expect, as illustrated above.

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(400px, 1fr))
```

With this rule, the grid items stack into a single column on smaller screens.

However, when you introduce explicit columns and rows, this interferes with the ability of `repeat()` and `auto-fit` to do their job.

```
grid-template-areas: "leftCol rightTop" "leftCol rightBottom"
```

This rule tells grid items where they need to be, stunting `repeat()`.

```
grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr
```

This rule creates a two-row limit in the container, pushing the third item off-screen.

In a nutshell, don't add rules that interfere with `repeat()` / `auto-fit`. If you need a more sophisticated layout, then use media queries.

Answer (score -6):

try using

css:

```
.grid-container div {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```